# About the usage of "though"

Tags: word-usage

Is the usage of "though" in the following sentence correct?

> It's said that it is a picture of a rabbit, but I'm sure enough that what I see is, **though**, a fish.

Don't mind the contents. What I want to ask is whether I can use "though" that way or not. If not, why?

Comment: Sure.  In this context, it means "however" or "nonetheless."

Comment: All of these linking adverbs -- they show what's cause and what's expected when several clauses are involved -- feel most natural at the beginning of the clause, but they can also float into other adverbial niches. Note that this is a use of _though_  and not of _although_; normally one can swap them around at will, but not here.

Answer (score 2):

I think that, after "but", there is no need for the "though".

I also agree with the above comments and "though" can stay where it is, but I would prefer: "It's said that it is a picture of a rabbit. I'm sure enough that what I see is, though, a fish." (leaving out "but") or - even better - "It's said that it is a picture of a rabbit, though I'm sure enough that what I see is a fish."

Answer (score 0):

'But' and '[al]though' are conjunctions and may be synonymous. '[Al]though' is subordinating so it can be fronted as in: 'Although it's a picture of a rabbit, I see a fish'.  '[Al]though' can also be used as an adverb synonymous with 'however'.